# Calculate driving distance between user location and many destinations via javascript loop

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3

I have a json feed with many locations:

> http://hcafeeds.medcity.net/rss/er/ntx_rss_feed.xml

I plan on obtaining the user's location via html5 geolocation. At this point, I'd like to loop through the json feed and output the items from the feed along with their distance from the user's location.

I've tried every which way I can with the google maps api but I always seem to hit a hurdle an hour into the method.

Has anyone done something similar?

UPDATE: here's my existing code

Will output the hospitals just fine... just can't figure out how to get distance:

```
  var hcafeed = 'http://hcafeeds.medcity.net/rss/er/ntx_rss_feed.xml';
  var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from rss where url="' + hcafeed + '"') + '&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=?';
  $.getJSON(yql,function(data){
    if(data.query.count > 0) {

      // Run through hospitals and set html
      var hospitals = [];
      $.each( data.query.results.item, function( key, val ) {
        var hospitalAddress = val.address;
        var wait = $.trim(val.description.replace("Mins",""));
        var units = (wait == 1) ? " Min" : " Mins";

        hospitals.push({
          'name' :        "<div class='name'>"+val.comments.replace(" ER Wait Time","")+"</div>",
          'addy' :        "<div class='addy'>"+val.address+"</div>",
          'phone' :       "<div class='phone'>"+val.phone+"</div>",
          'waitOutput' :  "<div class='wait'>"+wait+units+"</div>",
          'wait' :        wait,
          'distanceOutput' : "<div class='distance'></div>",
        });

      });

      // Sort array by wait time (default)
      hospitals.sort(function(a, b){
        return a.wait-b.wait;
      });

      // Prepare array for output (wrapper)
      var output = [];
      $.each( hospitals, function( key, val ) {
        output.push("<div data-key='"+key+"' data-wait='"+val.wait+"' class='hospital'>"+val.name+val.addy+val.phone+val.waitOutput+val.distanceOutput+"</div>");
      });
    }

    // Print array
    $("#hospitals").html( output );

  }).fail(function (j, t, e) {
     console.error(e);
  });
```

I've created a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/potd25yy/3/

Comment: That URL isn't JSON, it's XML (as you might guess from the file extension). Specifically, it's an RSS feed (which you may also guess from the filename). So first step is to forget about the Maps API and simply loop through the XML data to pull out the information you need, and `console.log()` it to see if you have that part right. This doesn't involve the Maps API at all. You can do it easily with jQuery, or with a little more work using the native DOM calls. After you've verified this part, then you can move on to the Maps API work.

Comment: Why an hour in? How many locations are you typically trying to geocode?

Comment: Post your code. And have you tried debugging? What are the results of the directions requests when it fails? etc. Note that directions requests are subject to usage limits.

Comment: @MichaelGeary - It was converted to JSON.

Comment: @Yaniv - What I meant was that I would have an ahah moment, then an hour into the method, I would realize that due to some async issue, I'd have to abort.

Comment: @PhilSmith your sample code doesn't contain any calls to a Google API, so I'm a bit confused about what you're asking. Please be specific about what you're trying and what is not working. The Distance Matrix API should be fine for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than a distance matrix, you should use the [Directions Service in Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) to calculate a path between your user's location and your hospital.

The function:

```
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
```

return a response, with multiple routes. And the distance of the first route would be:

```
response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text
```

so you can display it to the corresponding entry.

I create a quick demo to calculate the distance from Google, Inc. to each hospital. Hope this help. And let me know if you have further questions.

https://jsfiddle.net/jqw3g914/1/